# Perfect Assistant not working

Tags: ios, swift, perfect

Working with Perfect Assistant but not able to create new project getting error as below screenshot
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you trying to import a project? or creating a new project?

Comment: creating new one

Comment: I followed following link  https://perfect.org/en/assistant/creating-projects.html

Answer (score 2):

Perfect Assistant has been updated to 2.0: https://assistant.perfect.org/perfectassistant/Perfect%20Assistant.dmg

It just updated two days ago, so I think it will resolve your issue which was reported one month ago.

Answer (score 1):

**The Perfect Assistant will not create a project within a folder that already exists.**

The folder in which you are declaring your new Perfect project must be a *completely new* folder that doesn't already exist. So if you are creating a new project and you want to call it "My_New_Project" you will need to declare that the location you are going to place this in is a 'fresh' one. The best thing to do is to store this in your "Documents" folder on your machine.

In the Perfect Assistant -> create new project -> Select the location to save as Documents - and then after `/Documents` just type `/My_New_Project` to create a subfolder within your documents. Say done and this is where Perfect Assistant will set up your new project. It should look something like:

(the `...` the path to your documents folder in your system.)

`.../Documents/My_New_Project`